# D-SIFER algorithm in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sift

Is there a Matlab implementation of the D-SIFER algorithm, as described in [this paper](http://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~konijn/publications/2013/10.1007_s11263-013-0622-3.pdf) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment. The paper you are referring to is a research paper and most researchers do not post their codes publicly. But, many of them share the codes for academic and research purposes. 
You could try contacting the authors of the paper and see if they provide the code implementation for your need. That's the ideal approach in this case, as we shouldn't be using someone else's code without their consent.